# WHen I test varnish with curl -I http://localhost, I get:

Tags: magento, varnish

I'm trying to install and configure varnish in mey srever, and I think I've done it, altought when I run the teste i get:

curl -I http://localhost

HTTP/1.1 503 Backend fetch failed
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 17:16:50 GMT
Server: Varnish
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Retry-After: 5
X-Varnish: 32770
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
Connection: keep-alive

Can any expert help me?
For what i see i get this problem "HTTP/1.1 503 Backend fetch failed", I've already locate more memory but the problem persists...

Best regards,
Leonel Nunes

Answer (score 1):

- BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
- BereqHeader    Host: www.test.com
- BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 145.239.78.207
- BereqHeader    grace: none
- BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 30
- VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
- VCL_return     fetch
- BackendOpen    29 boot.default 145.239.78.207 8080 145.239.78.207 56942
- BackendStart   145.239.78.207 8080
- Timestamp      Bereq: 1568108230.028067 0.000121 0.000121
- BerespProtocol HTTP/1.0
- Timestamp      Beresp: 1568108230.030388 0.002443 0.002321
- BerespProtocol HTTP/1.0
- BerespStatus   200
- BerespReason   OK
- BerespHeader   Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019 09:37:10 GMT
- BerespHeader   Server: Apache
- BerespHeader   Last-Modified: Fri, 23 Aug 2019 01:46:14 GMT
- BerespHeader   Accept-Ranges: bytes
- BerespHeader   Content-Length: 7725
- BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
- BerespHeader   Expires: Wed, 09 Sep 2020 09:37:10 GMT
- BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
- BerespHeader   Connection: close
- BerespHeader   Content-Type: image/jpeg
- VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
- TTL            VCL -1 259200 0 1568108230
- TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1568108230
- VCL_return     deliver
- Storage        malloc Transient
- ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.0
- ObjStatus      200
- ObjReason      OK
- ObjHeader      Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019 09:37:10 GMT
- ObjHeader      Server: Apache
- ObjHeader      Last-Modified: Fri, 23 Aug 2019 01:46:14 GMT
- ObjHeader      Accept-Ranges: bytes
- ObjHeader      Content-Length: 7725
- ObjHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
- ObjHeader      Expires: Wed, 09 Sep 2020 09:37:10 GMT
- ObjHeader      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
- ObjHeader      Content-Type: image/jpeg
- Fetch_Body     3 length stream
- BackendClose   29 boot.default
- Timestamp      BerespBody: 1568108230.030469 0.002524 0.000082
- Length         7725
- BereqAcct      192 0 192 309 7725 8034
- End
- << Request  >> 38
- Begin          req 37 rxreq
- Timestamp      Start: 1568108230.176665 0.000000 0.000000
- Timestamp      Req: 1568108230.176665 0.000000 0.000000
- ReqStart       145.239.78.207 40768
- ReqMethod      GET
- ReqURL         /pub/static/version1567874318/frontend/Swissup/absolute/pt_PT/images/payments/ww.png
- ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
- ReqHeader      Host: www.test.com
- ReqHeader      Connection: close
- ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 145.239.78.207
- VCL_call       RECV
- ReqHeader      grace: none
- ReqURL         /pub/static/version1567874318/frontend/Swissup/absolute/pt_PT/images/payments/ww.png
- VCL_return     pass
- VCL_call       HASH
- VCL_return     lookup
- VCL_call       PASS
- VCL_return     fetch
- Link           bereq 39 pass
- Timestamp      Fetch: 1568108230.178857 0.002191 0.002191
- RespProtocol   HTTP/1.0
- RespStatus     200
- RespReason     OK
- RespHeader     Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019 09:37:10 GMT
- RespHeader     Server: Apache
- RespHeader     Last-Modified: Tue, 03 Sep 2019 16:11:49 GMT
- RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
- RespHeader     Content-Length: 1003
- RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public
- RespHeader     Expires: Wed, 09 Sep 2020 09:37:10 GMT
- RespHeader     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
- RespHeader     Content-Type: image/png
- RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
- RespHeader     X-Varnish: 38
- RespHeader     Age: 0
- RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
- VCL_call       DELIVER
- RespUnset      Age: 0
- VCL_return     deliver
- Timestamp      Process: 1568108230.178877 0.002212 0.000021
- RespHeader     Connection: close
- Timestamp      Resp: 1568108230.178912 0.002246 0.000035
- ReqAcct        155 0 155 363 1003 1366
- End
- << Session  >> 37
- Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
- SessOpen       145.239.78.207 40768 a0 145.239.78.207 80 1568108230.176609 26
- Link           req 38 rxreq
- SessClose      REQ_CLOSE 0.002
- End
- << BeReq    >> 98340
- Begin          bereq 98339 pass
- Timestamp      Start: 1568108230.180024 0.000000 0.000000
- BereqMethod    GET
- BereqURL       /pub/static/version1567874318/frontend/Swissup/absolute/pt_PT/images/payments/paypal.png
- BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
- BereqHeader    Host: www.test.com
- BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 145.239.78.207
- BereqHeader    grace: none
- BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 98340
- VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
- VCL_return     fetch
- BackendOpen    29 boot.default 145.239.78.207 8080 145.239.78.207 56974
- BackendStart   145.239.78.207 8080
- Timestamp      Bereq: 1568108230.180132 0.000108 0.000108
- BerespProtocol HTTP/1.0
- Timestamp      Beresp: 1568108230.181992 0.001968 0.001860
- BerespProtocol HTTP/1.0
- BerespStatus   200
- BerespReason   OK
- BerespHeader   Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019 09:37:10 GMT
- BerespHeader   Server: Apache
- BerespHeader   Last-Modified: Tue, 03 Sep 2019 16:11:49 GMT
- BerespHeader   Accept-Ranges: bytes
- BerespHeader   Content-Length: 1757
- BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public
- BerespHeader   Expires: Wed, 09 Sep 2020 09:37:10 GMT
- BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
- BerespHeader   Connection: close
- BerespHeader   Content-Type: image/png
- VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
- TTL            VCL -1 259200 0 1568108230
- TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1568108230
- VCL_return     deliver
- Storage        malloc Transient
- ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.0
- ObjStatus      200
- ObjReason      OK
- ObjHeader      Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019 09:37:10 GMT
- ObjHeader      Server: Apache
- ObjHeader      Last-Modified: Tue, 03 Sep 2019 16:11:49 GMT
- ObjHeader      Accept-Ranges: bytes
- ObjHeader      Content-Length: 1757
- ObjHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public
- ObjHeader      Expires: Wed, 09 Sep 2020 09:37:10 GMT
- ObjHeader      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
- ObjHeader      Content-Type: image/png
- Fetch_Body     3 length stream
- BackendClose   29 boot.default
- Timestamp      BerespBody: 1568108230.182080 0.002055 0.000088
- Length         1757
- BereqAcct      204 0 204 316 1757 2073
- End
- << Request  >> 98339
- Begin          req 98338 rxreq
- Timestamp      Start: 1568108230.179969 0.000000 0.000000
- Timestamp      Req: 1568108230.179969 0.000000 0.000000
- ReqStart       145.239.78.207 40772
- ReqMethod      GET
- ReqURL         /pub/static/version1567874318/frontend/Swissup/absolute/pt_PT/images/payments/paypal.png
- ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
- ReqHeader      Host: www.test.com
- ReqHeader      Connection: close
- ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 145.239.78.207
- VCL_call       RECV
- ReqHeader      grace: none
- ReqURL         /pub/static/version1567874318/frontend/Swissup/absolute/pt_PT/images/payments/paypal.png
- VCL_return     pass
- VCL_call       HASH
- VCL_return     lookup
- VCL_call       PASS
- VCL_return     fetch
- Link           bereq 98340 pass
- Timestamp      Fetch: 1568108230.182061 0.002092 0.002092
- RespProtocol   HTTP/1.0
- RespStatus     200
- RespReason     OK
- RespHeader     Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019 09:37:10 GMT
- RespHeader     Server: Apache
- RespHeader     Last-Modified: Tue, 03 Sep 2019 16:11:49 GMT
- RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
- RespHeader     Content-Length: 1757
- RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public
- RespHeader     Expires: Wed, 09 Sep 2020 09:37:10 GMT
- RespHeader     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
- RespHeader     Content-Type: image/png
- RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
- RespHeader     X-Varnish: 98339
- RespHeader     Age: 0
- RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
- VCL_call       DELIVER
- RespUnset      Age: 0
- VCL_return     deliver
- Timestamp      Process: 1568108230.182087 0.002118 0.000026
- RespHeader     Connection: close
- Timestamp      Resp: 1568108230.182146 0.002177 0.000058
- ReqAcct        159 0 159 366 1757 2123
- End

Comment: the answers are even more stupid than varnish

Answer (score 0):

Not enough detail for a succinct answer.

To cut the problem in-half, try to browse http address of the backend server?

Another important consideration, Have you properly configured, /etc/varnish/user.vcl ?

Here is a Varnish tutorial... https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/varnish/getting-started-with-varnish-cache/

Finally, find the location of the Varnish log file to get more details.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the quick reply, Yes it's weel configured, and how I try to browse the backend server :S ?   The version of varnish is 5.2, running on centos 6 ...

Comment: Hello again, running logs I get some informations and this, wish I think it's the problem: VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR

Answer (score 0):

I will post a complete log:

varnishlog
*   << BeReq    >> 84
-   Begin          bereq 83 fetch
-   Timestamp      Start: 1566844978.393604 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /index.php/giantpointsadmin/adminhtml_earning_rate/index
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    Host: www.test.pt
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 51.89.7.90
-   BereqHeader    grace: none
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 84
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   FetchError     no backend connection
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1566844978.393680 0.000077 0.000077
-   Timestamp      Error: 1566844978.393687 0.000083 0.000007
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   503
-   BerespReason   Service Unavailable
-   BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
-   BerespHeader   Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 18:42:58 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ObjStatus      503
-   ObjReason      Backend fetch failed
-   ObjHeader      Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 18:42:58 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Server: Varnish
-   ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   ObjHeader      Retry-After: 5
-   Length         279
-   BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
-   End

- << Request  >> 83
- Begin          req 82 rxreq
- Timestamp      Start: 1566844978.384062 0.000000 0.000000
- Timestamp      Req: 1566844978.393264 0.009202 0.009202
- ReqStart       51.89.7.90 55715
- ReqMethod      GET
- ReqURL         /index.php/giantpointsadmin/adminhtml_earning_rate/index
- ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
- ReqHeader      Host: www.test.pt
- ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive
- ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
- ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36
- ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 51.89.7.90
- VCL_call       RECV
- ReqHeader      grace: none
- ReqURL         /index.php/giantpointsadmin/adminhtml_earning_rate/index
- ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
- ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
- VCL_return     hash
- VCL_call       HASH
- VCL_return     lookup
- VCL_call       MISS
- VCL_return     fetch
- Link           bereq 84 fetch
- Timestamp      Fetch: 1566844978.393832 0.009770 0.000568
- RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
- RespStatus     503
- RespReason     Backend fetch failed
- RespHeader     Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 18:42:58 GMT
- RespHeader     Server: Varnish
- RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
- RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
- RespHeader     X-Varnish: 83
- RespHeader     Age: 0
- RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
- VCL_call       DELIVER
- VCL_return     deliver
- Timestamp      Process: 1566844978.393857 0.009795 0.000025
- RespHeader     Content-Length: 279
- RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
- Timestamp      Resp: 1566844978.393929 0.009868 0.000072
- ReqAcct        266 0 266 247 279 526
- End
- << Session  >> 82
- Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
- SessOpen       51.89.7.90 55715 a0 145.239.78.207 80 1566844978.383924 25
- Link           req 83 rxreq
- SessClose      REM_CLOSE 0.020
- End
- << BeReq    >> 32855
- Begin          bereq 32854 pass
- Timestamp      Start: 1566844978.423125 0.000000 0.000000
- BereqMethod    POST
- BereqURL       /index.php/giantpointsadmin/adminhtml_earning_rate/index/
- BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
- BereqHeader    Host: www.test.pt
- BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
- BereqHeader    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------7O12ZqAnhn621bBI
- BereqHeader    Content-Length: 326
- BereqHeader    User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.0); U) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16
- BereqHeader    Cookie: adminhtml=86g8r80a2uhrf66b95f2lnslo0
- BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 51.89.7.90
- BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 32855
- VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
- VCL_return     fetch
- FetchError     no backend connection
- Timestamp      Beresp: 1566844978.423157 0.000033 0.000033
- Timestamp      Error: 1566844978.423165 0.000040 0.000008
- BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
- BerespStatus   503
- BerespReason   Service Unavailable
- BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
- BerespHeader   Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 18:42:58 GMT
- BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
- VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
- BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
- BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
- VCL_return     deliver
- Storage        malloc Transient
- ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
- ObjStatus      503
- ObjReason      Backend fetch failed
- ObjHeader      Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 18:42:58 GMT
- ObjHeader      Server: Varnish
- ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
- ObjHeader      Retry-After: 5
- Length         282
- BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
- End
- << Request  >> 32854
- Begin          req 32853 rxreq
- Timestamp      Start: 1566844978.413495 0.000000 0.000000
- Timestamp      Req: 1566844978.422953 0.009458 0.009458
- ReqStart       51.89.7.90 55717
- ReqMethod      POST
- ReqURL         /index.php/giantpointsadmin/adminhtml_earning_rate/index/
- ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
- ReqHeader      Host: www.test.pt
- ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive
- ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
- ReqHeader      Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------7O12ZqAnhn621bBI
- ReqHeader      Content-Length: 326
- ReqHeader      User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.0); U) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16
- ReqHeader      Cookie: adminhtml=86g8r80a2uhrf66b95f2lnslo0
- ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 51.89.7.90
- VCL_call       RECV
- VCL_return     pass
- VCL_call       HASH
- VCL_return     lookup
- VCL_call       PASS
- VCL_return     fetch
- Link           bereq 32855 pass
- Timestamp      Fetch: 1566844978.423294 0.009799 0.000341
- Storage        malloc Transient
- Timestamp      ReqBody: 1566844978.423314 0.009819 0.000020
- RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
- RespStatus     503
- RespReason     Backend fetch failed
- RespHeader     Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2019 18:42:58 GMT
- RespHeader     Server: Varnish
- RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
- RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
- RespHeader     X-Varnish: 32854
- RespHeader     Age: 0
- RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
- VCL_call       DELIVER
- VCL_return     deliver
- Timestamp      Process: 1566844978.423336 0.009841 0.000022
- RespHeader     Content-Length: 282
- RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
- Timestamp      Resp: 1566844978.423392 0.009897 0.000056
- ReqAcct        374 326 700 250 282 532
- End
- << Session  >> 32853
- Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
- SessOpen       51.89.7.90 55717 a0 145.239.78.207 80 1566844978.413439 24
- Link           req 32854 rxreq
- SessClose      REM_CLOSE 0.020
- End

Best regards,
Leonel Nunes

Comment: no backend connection, what do you backends (in vcl) look like?

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply, in vcl backend default is like this: backend default {
    .host = "Server Ip";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
}

Comment: Ok, so there's no probe. the FetchError occurs super fast (0.000033s), so it looks like we can't even reach the backend. Are you able to "curl $serverIP:8080/" from the varnish machine?

Comment: Hello and thanks again for the support :)..When I run that command I get "curl: (7) couldn't connect to host"...

Comment: there's you problem then, the varnish node doesn't have access to the backend, either because there's no server software on it listening to 8080, or maybe because of a firewall between the two

Comment: Hello and thanks for helping me, humm, ok, so it might be a firewall problem, I will check if port is in allowed ports

Comment: Hello, well, now after curl http://serverIP:8080
<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-control" CONTENT="no-cache"><META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi"></head><body></body></html>

Comment: can you pastebin a new varnishlog (of the BeReq) now that we have checked that there's connectivity?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, yes, I will post a new log right now